# How many corners does an otherwise intrinsically flat surface need in order to be homeomorphic to a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I want to build a virtual world that feels like an unbounded flat plane but actually "connects back to itself" with the topology of a sphere. To do this, we can build the world out of polygonal sectors corresponding to the faces of a polyhedron (bordering each other in the same configuration). This works nicely except that each vertex of the polyhedron becomes a weird point, around which a small loop has a total turning angle less than 360°. (For example, if the polyhedron is a cube, each vertex is the meeting point of three square sectors, so you can walk all the way around it while making just three quarter-turns.) We can still render these locations using a portal technique and put something like a tall tree at each one to obscure the visual discontinuity.

To make these "corners" less conspicuous, I'll use a polyhedron with a large number of vertices. But if we didn't care about that, how few corners could we theoretically get away with? I think the smallest polyhedron that makes sense with my construction is a double-sided triangle, which has 3 corners. But what about a space like a cylinder with each end pinched together (2 corners), or the one-point compactification of a flat open disk (1 corner)? I can't visualize 3D embeddings of these that preserve flatness, but could there still be a corresponding "flat world" with just one or two singular points?

In order to answer this, I think I need to clarify the idea of a "manifold with corners", and that's where I'm having trouble. I've thought about cutting the corners off (leaving a small boundary loop) or rounding them off (leaving a small region with nonzero curvature) to obtain an actual manifold (on which the Gauss-Bonnet theorem might be helpful), but I'm not sure how to express the requirement that the resulting defect is still "point-sized", which seems important. Inside the flatworld, I want the singularity to appear as a "pole" standing on a point of the plane (as opposed to some larger object), and I think this is what could rule out the one- or two-corner possibilities.

Comment: You'll need to make "noticeable" precise

Comment: There is an amusing way to make a game space a torus, which goes back to the old game, Asteroids. You play on a rectangle and when you go off one side, you arrive on the opposite side. This gives zero corners - the space looks entirely flat to the gamer - if you center the view on the ship at all times, you cannot distinguish one point from the other. I don't think it is possible for a sphere, though.

Comment: Yeah, a torus has zero [total curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature), so we can make a completely flat world with torus topology. Since a sphere has nonzero total curvature, we need some places that aren't flat.

Comment: Is this what you're fishing for? Define a flat manifold-with-corners to be a surface equipped with a metric that has one of the following local models: the ordinary Euclidean plane metric; or, for any angle $0 < \theta < 2\pi$, the intrinsic metric on a circular cone in $\mathbb R^3$ whose angle around the cone point is $\theta$. For any such metric on any closed surface, the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem does indeed imply that the sum of $2 \pi - \theta$ over the cone points is equal to the Euler characteristic.

Comment: @LeeMosher That sounds like what I'm after, yes! I might be confused about something - I was assuming these spaces don't admit a manifold structure because the corners aren't smooth, but maybe you're suggesting that the corner-ness can be encoded in a Riemannian metric on a surface that *is* smooth even at the corners? I'll have to read about these metrics.

Comment: A double-sided triangle is not a polyhedron in $R^3$. What exactly do you mean by a polyhedron?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess by polyhedron I really just mean a space made of finitely many polygons glued along matched-up edges to give the desired topological structure. I think that's all I need for the "polygonal sectors" construction to make sense.

Comment: I see; it is usually called a "2-dimensional Euclidean polygonal complex." The faces are Euclidean planar polygons and the gluing maps are required to be isometric. Then, indeed, 3 is the lowest number (which is obvious once you have a clear definition).

Comment: That makes sense! Even though most of my post is describing that polygonal construction, my question comes down to spaces that *don't* arise in that way (but are still "flat except at a few points" in a sense that needs clarification).

Answer (score 2):

I've convinced myself that 3 corners are necessary, based on a sort of unsatisfying description of what a corner is. I'd still appreciate an answer with more clarity on how to define a topological space that's "flat except at corners" and what's wrong with the proposed cylinder/disk quotient spaces.

The idea is: For a corner to be "point-like", you should be able to walk a small counterclockwise loop around it, keeping it on your left and ending up with a total left turn angle of $\theta>0$, which measures the angular size of the space surrounding the corner. Since $\theta>0$, the "deficit" $2\pi-\theta$ must be strictly less than $2\pi$. By the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), the deficit measures the curvature at the corner, and if the surface is flat except at the corners, the sum of the deficits must be $4\pi$. (We can verify this for various polygons.) But this means we need strictly more than 2 corners.

Comment: You are correct. See this paper by Troyanov, in particular the first Proposition at page 2 https://www.jstor.org/stable/2001742 . What you are asking for is a flat metric with conical singularities on the sphere, such that every conical point has angle strictly between $0$ and $2\pi$. This can be achieved if and only if the topological constraint coming from Gauss-Bonet is satisfied (see the paper), and your constraints force the number of cone singularities to be at least $3$. Hope this was useful!

Comment: By the way, the flat sphere with 4 conical singularities is sometimes called the "pillowcase". I guess it is easy to guess where the name comes from (: